# How can i get list of values which are not repeated in Grails with <g:select >tag

Tags: grails, groovy

i have one drop down which is to be displayed only non repeated values.

It displays all colonies with duplicates,but i dont need any duplicate values.
how ca i do that.

Thanks in advance.
Odaiah